# preg_match not returning expected results

Tags: php, regex

I'm attempting to use regexp to parse a search string that from time to time may contain special syntax. The syntax  im looking for is [special keyword : value] and i want each match put into an array. Keep in mind that the search string will contain other text that is not intended to be parsed.

```
$searchString = "[StartDate:2010-11-01][EndDate:2010-11-31]";
$specialKeywords = array();
preg_match("/\[{1}.+\:{1}.+\]{1}/", $searchString, $specialKeywords);
var_dump($specialKeywords);
```

Output:

> array(1) { [0]=> string(43) "[StartDate:2010-11-01] [EndDate:2010-11-31]" }

Desired Output:

> array(2) { [0]=> string() "[StartDate:2010-11-01]"
>
> [1]=> string() "[EndDate:2010-11-01]"}

Please let me know if i am not being clear enough.

Comment: The quantifier `{1}` is useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `.+` matches across the boundaries between the two `[...]` parts because it matches any character, and as many of them as possible. You could be more restrictive about which characters may be matched. Also `{1}` is redundant and can be dropped.

```
/\[[^:]*:[^\]]*\]/
```

should work more reliably.

**Explanation:**

```
\[     # match a [
[^:]*  # match any number of characters except :
:      # match a :
[^\]]* # match any number of characters except ]
\]     # match a ]
```

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly, i had to use the preg_match_all to get the array built correctly but the expression was spot on. Thanks again

Comment: Can you go into a little more detail into the explanation.  I'm confused how `[^:]*` = `match any number of characters except :`. Is the `[^:]*` matching all characters up until the `:` because the `:` is in the regex?

Comment: @Derek Adair: The `[^:]*` matches as many non-`:`-characters as it can, so it matches all characters up to (but not including) the `:`. This behaviour is independent from whether there is a `:` following in the regex or not - but of course it makes sense here. It also helps to match as quickly as possible because the regex engine never has to backtrack.

Comment: so [^something]* would match any number of characters that are not `something` until it reached `something`?

Comment: More or less, yes. `[^abc]+` means "match one or more characters except `a`, `b` or `c`. So in `abcdefcba` it will match `def`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$searchString = "[StartDate:2010-11-01][EndDate:2010-11-31]";
$specialKeywords = array();
preg_match_all("/\[\w+:\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d\]/i", $searchString, $specialKeywords);

var_dump($specialKeywords[0]);
```

Outputs:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(22) "[StartDate:2010-11-01]"
  [1]=>
  string(20) "[EndDate:2010-11-31]"
}
```

Comment: He needs start/end date, not 2 end dates

Comment: @Webnet Yeeea, I should really *look* at the output before I copy/paste it into an answer.

Comment: Thank you for the response, the problem i see with the expression you provided is that the value will not always be in Y-m-d format.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
$searchString = "[StartDate:2010-11-01][EndDate:2010-11-31]";
preg_match_all('/\[.*?\]/', $searchString, $match);

print_r($match);
```

gives the expected result, I'm not sure if it matches all the constraints.

Comment: Thank you for the response, the preg_match_all was a missing component but the expression from another answer was closer to what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex: `"/\[(.*?)\:(.*?)\]{1}/"` and also use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/preg_match_all), it will return

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(22) "[StartDate:2010-11-01]"
    [1]=>
    string(20) "[EndDate:2010-11-31]"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "StartDate"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "EndDate"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2010-11-01"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "2010-11-31"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/\[.+?\:.+?\]/
```

I suggest this method, less complex but it handles the same as tim's